# Never select navbar button - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar like this one:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/slider/#/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

But I don´t want a blue background as selection. (when I click on a button)

I only want to execute the action and not fill the background blue.

Comment: Isn't that simply to do with your css?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Y9pXL/

```
.ui-focus, .ui-btn:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent !important;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 transparent !important;
}

.ui-btn-active {
    border-width: 0px !important;
    background:transparent !important;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(transparent),to(transparent))!important;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)!important;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)!important;
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)!important;
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)!important;
    background-image:linear-gradient(transparent,transparent)!important;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the bottom navbar with friends email, ...

There is also a selection. (black)
And the others are black-grey.

I don´t wanna see any different...